# Renaming dataframe columns via User Defined Function via Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i'm trying to rename dataframe columns through **User Defined Function** without success.
In particular it seems that doesn't exist "rename" method when called inside a **UDF**.
Following an example to better explain my problem:

```
import pandas as pd`

data = {'Age': [21, 19, 20, 18,80,90],'Stream': [88, 65,99, 765,65,55],'Percentage': [88, 92, 95, 70,55,47]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Age', 'Stream', 'Percentage'])

print("Given Dataframe :n", df)

def modname(frame):


    frame=frame.rename(columns={'Age':'aa','Stream':'bb','Percentage':'cc'})
    
    return frame

df=df.apply(modname)

print(df)
```

`

I greatly appreciate your help

i tried the same code without **UDF** and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
df=df.apply(modname)
```

You should do:

```
df = modname(df)
```

Comment: thanks for your contribute, but unfortunately the dataframe doesn't change its original columns, despite there are not errors in output

Comment: ok, i have modified                                                                                                                       frame.rename(columns={'Age':'aa','Stream':'bb','Percentage':'cc'},inplace=True)                   and now it works

Comment: It is weird that the solution I proposed didn’t do the job. I tested it. Do you mind sharing the full code with my solution (no inplace) that didn’t work for you? I’m curious.

Comment: thanks Diego, your solution works pretty well too, i've retested it now. I don't understand the reason why in the first test doesn't works, perhaps for a my mistake

Comment: Amazing Paoli. I’m glad to help you !